# Symbolic link doesn't work across drives

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, symbolic-link, mklink

I'm on Windows 10.

Running the command:

```
mklink /D "G:\test" "C:\test"
```

...Is successful. However, in explorer when I double click the folder on G:\ and try to access any file in there, it says "file does not exist, create it?".

The weird thing is that this has worked perfectly fine before today, and also:

It seems to work when on the same drive. If I run

```
mklink /D "C:\new1" "C:\test"
```

I have no problems accessing it in explorer.

Comment: If you are still around: What does `G:\ >dir /A` show?